# References about Quantum Theory

Tags: mathematical-physics, quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, quantum-groups, topological-quantum-field-theory

I’m interested in Quantum Theory. Can anyone recommend a good book (for mathematicians) that tackles varios topics (not necessarily formally).
I have in mind books that have the same idea of books like “What is Mathematics” or “All the math you missed (but need for Graduate School”.

Thanks!

Comment: How much do you already know?

Comment: For some suggestions see [Where does a math person go to learn quantum mechanics?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/2917/15780) *AND* [Quantum mechanics for mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/38916/13130) *AND* [Quantum mechanical books for mathematicians](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2348939/13130).

Comment: @insipidintegrator I did my master’s thesis in the metaplectic and spin representation for bosonic and fermionic Fock spaces, respectively.